# Error while importing vault 1.3.0 go mod error

Tags: go, hashicorp-vault, vault

While trying to import
github.com/hashicorp/vault/api v1.3.0 in the require field, i am facing the issue.

```
Command 'gopls.update_go_sum' failed: Error: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: github.com/hashicorp/vault/api@v1.3.0: reading github.com/hashicorp/vault/api/api/go.mod at revision api/v1.3.0: unknown revision api/v1.3.0 .
```

I have seen some solution to use the replace and all but not sure.

Any help is appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running this `go mod tidy`

Comment: @Ashok I had tried that earlier but was facing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Error precisely mentions that `api/v1.3.0` revision is unknown since the latest revision is `api/v1.1.1`.

Link: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/releases/tag/api%2Fv1.1.1

If you want to know more about why this is happening, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60601402

Comment: Thanks. Ya i got confused with the other version that i saw.