# Why module gets imported by pseudo-version from multi-module repo?

Tags: go, go-modules

Some Go projects use multi-module approach, where top directory contains one module and  subdir another. For example

- Nomad server https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad
- Nomad API https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/tree/main/api

When importing the submodule from `api` directory to my own project, it gets included with pseudo-version such as `v0.0.0-20220310213507-4a21dbcfaa6e` even though the git repository does have release tags.
Trying to force specific release tag by running `go get github.com/hashicorp/nomad/api@v1.2.6` will result in error:

```
go get: module github.com/hashicorp/nomad@v1.2.6 found, but does not contain package github.com/hashicorp/nomad/api
```

Why doesn't Go pick up release tags in this case?

Comment: Separate modules are versioned independently, and Go supports hierarchical git tags. The `api` module doesn't seem to be versioned for that project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601011/how-are-versions-of-a-sub-module-managed

Comment: Thank you @JimB! That is the correct answer.  There should be tag `api/v1.2.6`. I submitted a request to the project to start versioning the submodule.